# Rapid svn error on checkout and update/commit

Tags: svn, rapidsvn

I've been using **rapid svn** for a while.

Now I got this strange problem. When I checkout a folder rapid svn shows file transferring but the checkout folder is empty.

- When I try to update or commit it shows the folder does not exist error?

I tried reinstalling **rapidsvn** ,removed all .svn files ,it didnt work.

- Any help?

Comment: What error do you get?